# Does Git Pull Merge Changes Automatically

Tags: git

I have a local Git repository with 2 remotes. Each repo has 2 branches, like so:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
+ repo                | branches                                      +
+ --------------------------------------------------------------------+
+ local               | master                                        +
+                     | development                                   +
+ remote - origin     | master                                        +
+                     | development                                   +
+ remote - live       | master                                        +
+                     | development                                   +
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For reasons too complicated to explain, we only ever push to origin on the remote, which checks out to live. If I want to pull changes from the live repo, development branch to my local master branch, I issue the command:

```
(jongosi@cent.local) branch::master $ git pull live development
```

**My question**: does that single command pull the changes to both the master *and* development branches locally?

When I checkout development locally and `git merge master`, it says `Already up-to-date.` How did the changes get into the local development branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git pull in the way that you are currently running it will pull the changes from the development branch from the live remote repo into your current local branch (master), and merge them. Therefore, when you try to merge your local master branch (which is now a merged copy of master and live/development) with your local development branch, it is up to date because you just pulled it to reflect the development branch.

To answer your question directly, it DOES NOT pull the changes to both the master and development, just master.

From http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull with reference to git pull

> git pull runs git fetch with the given parameters and calls git merge to merge the retrieved branch heads into the current branch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm still not clear on how the changes get into the local development branch without being pulled or merged? If Git doesn't pull the changes to local development, how come `you just pulled it to reflect the development branch`? I will research accordingly.

Comment: Do this: look at your development branch, checkout your master branch and do the pull, then checkout your development branch again - the code that was there before the pull will still be there, unaltered.

Comment: Correct! I must have made some noob mistake... development branch on local doesn't update. Thx a heap!